# Multiple 404 error pages in Laravel - changing layout

Tags: php, laravel, referrer, laravel-blade

I have multiple designs in one site, so what I need to do is serve up specific pages with the correct design template. In this case I'm trying to give 404 the proper master layout.

I currently working with the following, but PHP in blades isn't the way to go so that might be whee I'm getting lost.

I grab the referrer, look for the folder, and issue the correct layout:

```
$referer = Request::referer();

if (strpos($referer,'ext') !== false) {
   echo "@extends('layouts.ext_2.master')";
} else {
    echo "@extends('layouts.master')";
}
```

Route:

```
App::missing(function($exception) {
    return Response::view('error-404', array(), 404);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better for you to handle this in your controller and return different views for each condition:

```
$referer = Request::referer();

if (strpos($referer,'ext') !== false) {
   return view('layouts.ext_2.master');
} else {
    return view('layouts.master');
}
```

If, for some reason, you want to have condition logic in a template, you could just pass variable to a view, I think it's much safer:

```
$referer = Request::referer();

$layout = (strpos($referer,'ext') ? 'layouts.ext_2.master' : 'layouts.master';

    return view('main.view', compact('layout'));
}
```

And in the view:

```
@include($layout)
```

Comment: This makes sense, but would the second option still go in the controller or in the route? I've updated my question to include my error route.

Comment: You can use some logic in a route if you want (inside function, before `return` clause).